# How can I send a request header named Cookie from internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Following code works

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Cookie1',Value);
```

But when I change it to

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Cookie',Value);
```

The browser just ignore the command. I need to send header named 'Cookie' for a API. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because [the `Cookie` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#section-4.3.4) has a predefined meaning. It's for browser cookies. You can't set it explicitly.

It seems unlikely that an API is asking you to send a request header called `Cookie`. Perhaps you're meant to *actually* send a cookie (which can you can do via [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)).